# Improve categories sprite menu with responsiveness and title attribute

Tags: html, css, menu

I have something like

```
#categories{width:1042px;height:170px;margin:15px 0px 0px 0px;}
#categorieMenu{background:url(../images/categories.jpg) no-repeat;width:1042px;height:170px;margin:0;padding:0;}
#categorieMenu li,#categorieMenu a{height:170px;display:block;}
#categorieMenu li{float:left;list-style:none;display:inline;text-indent:-9999em;}
#categorie_1{width:174px;}
#categorie_2{width:175px;}
#categorie_3{width:174px;}
#categorie_4{width:175px;}
#categorie_5{width:174px;}
#categorie_6{width:170px;}
#categorie_1 a:hover{background:url(../images/categories.jpg) 0px -170px no-repeat;}
#categorie_2 a:hover{background:url(../images/categories.jpg) -174px -170px no-repeat;}
#categorie_3 a:hover{background:url(../images/categories.jpg) -349px -170px no-repeat;}
#categorie_4 a:hover{background:url(../images/categories.jpg) -523px -170px no-repeat;}
#categorie_5 a:hover{background:url(../images/categories.jpg) -698px -170px no-repeat;}
#categorie_6 a:hover{background:url(../images/categories.jpg) -872px -170px no-repeat;}
```

and an image categories.jpg

[image]

that changes depending on hover. It works fine however I would like to make it responsive and maybe a harder improvement to give tittle to each category as an attribute, so the name of category does not depend on the image title

How would the code look like to enable this attributes to this menu?

[Here is the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BdZW4/1/)

How can I get something like the image:
[image]

I added only the last categorie "Employee Certification"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done  a fiddle check this

http://jsfiddle.net/Shinov/p88LW/

```
#categorie_1 {
 width:16.6%;   
}

#categorie_2 {
 width:16.6%;
}
#categorie_3 {
 width:16.6%;
}
#categorie_4 {
 width:16.6%;
}
#categorie_5 {
  width:16.6%;
}
#categorie_6 {
 width:16.6%;
}
```

Comment: One more question, How to add the title "Employee Certification" in both no hover and on hover situations?

Comment: i dint get your question properly..you can try removing

text-indent:-9999em; form #categorieMenu li